# VS Code Remote-SSH won't reconnect to one specific working directory on remote Ubuntu host

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

I'm using VSCode 1.72.2 with Remote-SSH v0.90.1 on Windows to develop against an AWS EC2 VM running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  A couple days ago, I was working in my project source folder in `/opt/t4/` on the target host.  When I was finished, I stopped the VM from the AWS console, forgetting that VS Code was still SSHed in.

When I brought the VM back up, I can reconnect VS Code/Remote-SSH to the host as before, *except* that I can no longer connect using `/opt/t4/` as my working directory.  I can use any directory except the one I was using when I disconnected.

I can navigate down to it and work in it if I use `/opt/` as my working directory.  I can navigate to it by manually SSHing to the remote host.  I can create a subfolder in a remote shell at `/opt/t4/test/`, and then connect VS Code using that subfolder as my working directory.  I can *see* and *select* `/opt/t4/` in the Open Folder dialog in VS Code. But when I try to connect using that working directory, the connection times out with a not-particularly-useful error message:

```
[00:05:49.867] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+my.remote.host", attempt 2, (Reconnection)
[00:05:49.868] SSH Resolver called for host: my.remote.host
[00:05:49.868] Setting up SSH remote "my.remote.host"
[00:05:49.870] Using commit id "d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075" and quality "stable" for server
[00:05:49.872] Install and start server if needed
[00:05:49.874] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\me\.ssh\config"
[00:05:49.874] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 1518 -F "C:\Users\me\.ssh\config" "my.remote.host" bash
[00:05:49.875] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[00:06:06.876] Resolver error: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
    at g.Timeout (c:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:585348)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (c:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:679743)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
[00:06:06.877] ------
```

- I tried `Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host` from VS Code.
- I tried deleting `~/.vscode-server` on the Linux host from an SSH session.
- I tried `Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host` from VS Code.
- I tried `Remote-SSH: Kill Local Connection Server for Host` from VS Code.
- I tried deleting and recreating the host connection details in the local config file from SSH-Remote.
- I tried rebooting both local and target hosts.
- I tried setting `/opt/` as my working dir, then deleting and recreating `/opt/t4`. I *was* able to do this, but as soon as I try reconnecting using `/opt/t4` as the working dir, VS Code still fails to connect.

I'm... stumped. My suspicion is that there is something corrupt cached Windows-side, but I don't know where to look for that.

Comment: Someone at my place of work is having the same issue but with connection to an Azure VM

Comment: Resetting the vscode cache on the client sorted our issue although it's incredibly inconvenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the link from @Mike Barry, I managed to find the local workspace for that target folder and delete it to force it to reinitialize, which cleared the issue.

Deleted C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\[guid]\ and reconnected with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is aware and working on a fix. There are a variety of workarounds in this thread: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7324